# How do I hide a page from readonly users in Sharepoint 2013 without changing permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

In the page properties there is a Hidden Page property which doesn't appear to have any effect on readonly users when I set it to true. Is there a way of setting a page as hidden so that readonly users do not see it in site contents or navigation?

Comment: Try to add security groups. Normal people with read only should be in "StandardUser" group, and make other "SecretUser"  group that can see this thing, that you want to hide.

Comment: That can be done but what about the Hidden Page property - does this actually do anything? If it works it would be a lot easier than messing about with permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you find out user has read only permissions, you can hide the page following option.

Go to **Site Actions--> Site Settings--> Navigation**
Here you can hide sub sites and pages.

You can achieve through coding itself.